# LINQ connection string location

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ in visual studio using the DataClasses 
Where can I change the connection string from the code?

Comment: Do you mean Linq-to-SQL?  Where you have a .dbml file in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add a connection string to your project's App.config or Web.config, then  when you instantiate your data context, you should be able to supply the name of the connection string to use.  e.g.:

## App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connectionName" value="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

## Code using data context

```
var context = new DataContext( "connectionName" );
```